# LDAP verify a password outside of code

Tags: ldap

I have an LDAP error in c# code talking about an invalid customers username / password.

I need to confirm if the password is in fact correct, or the way I have manipulated the users DN to remove the escape characters has caused the user to be unknown.

I'm not that familiar with domains and how that fits in with windows, but I have access to some free LDAP browsers e.g. http://www.ldapbrowser.com/ or can download some other software but I need to validate a password with it somehow.

Any ideas how?

Answer (score 1):

The "ldapbrowser" should work.

We prefer the http://directory.apache.org/studio/

What is the error code?

I assume you are using AD?

We also have some [help with AD and LDAP](http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20and%20Active%20Directory)

Answer (score 0):

See my reply to the following thread:

[LDAP - How to check a username/password combination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066265/ldap-how-to-check-a-username-password-combination/17765363#17765363)

If you need to only verify username and password, The LDAPWhoAmI Extended Operation will work (either in a custom test script, or via the dedicated binary 'ldapwhoami').

I hope this helps...

Max