# Authentication against Active Directory with C++ on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, active-directory, kerberos

I'm surprised there's so few examples on this out there.  I basically need to do a user/pass authentication against Active Directory.  I'm able to initialize a connection to active directory, but it always gives me an "Invalid Credentials" error.  I'm wondering if I'm passing it something wrong.  This is my first attempt with LDAP.  For that matter, I'm open to another (well documented perhaps) solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LDAP_SERVER "ldap://hq.mydomain.local/"

#include <ldap.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    LDAP    *ld;
    int     version( LDAP_VERSION3 );
    int     rc;
    char    bind_dn[100];
    berval  creds;
    berval* serverCreds;

    if( ldap_initialize( &ld, LDAP_SERVER ) ) {
        std::cerr << "Error initializing ldap..." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ldap_set_option( ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &version );

    creds.bv_val = "password";
    creds.bv_len = strlen("password");

    rc = ldap_sasl_bind_s( ld, "sAMAccountName=MYDOMAIN\\UserName,dc=mydomain,dc=local", "GSSAPI", &creds, NULL, NULL, &serverCreds );

    if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: " << ldap_err2string( rc ) << std::endl; 
        return 1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

EDIT:

I wanted to make sure everything is okay on the server side, so did some tests with ldapsearch.  It did not work at first, but I finally got it (with ldapsearch, anyway).

```
ldapsearch -D first.last@mydomain.local -H "ldap://hq.mydomain.local:389" -b "ou=Development,ou=Domain Users,dc=mydomain,dc=local" -W "sAMAccountName=first.last"
```

Maybe not the best way.  For starters, the key is the -D argument, and passing sAMAccountName at the end.  I'm not going to have the common name - only the windows login name, and their password.  The above command will show a user his info, if the password passes.

The caveat (I think) is that ldap_sasl_bind_s() has no equivalent of setting the -D (binddn) flag.  Looking at [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16323575/ldap-authentication-ldap-sasl-bind-s-not-working-but-ldap-simple-bind-s-works) it looks like ldap_interactive_bind_s() might, but it's a bit more involved, as I have to pass a call back.

With the example above where I set a password, but no binddn/username of any kind, who does it assume I'm trying to authenticate as?

Comment: Hi! I've never worked with Active Directory before but I'm trying to do something similar on Ubuntu 20.04. When I try to reproduce your example the compiler can't find `ldap.h` and also the command `locate ldap.h` yields nothing. It might be a dumb question but what do I need to install to get that library? I found a lot of LDAP-related instructions online but nothing seems to work so far.

Answer (score 2):

> sAMAccountName=MYDOMAIN\UserName,dc=mydomain,dc=local

This format of username is incorrect.  You do not need to specify `sAMAccountName` in your username and don't need to specify `dc` unless you're using `Distinguished Name`. You have few options for username.

1. **Distinguished Name**

> CN=Jeff Smith,OU=Sales,DC=Fabrikam,DC=Com

2. **sAMaccountName**

> jsmith

3. **The user path from a previous version of Windows**

> "Fabrikam\jeffsmith".

4. **User Principal Name (UPN)**

> jeffsmith@Fabrikam.com

Having said that, I'm not certain if the username is the only issue you're experiencing. I have not run your code locally.

Although this answer may not directly answer your question, since I have not tested this code in Linux machine, it could give you an idea or put you in a right direction. *I will not be surprised if this method is Windows specific only.*

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675161(v=vs.85).aspx) there're few `methods` you can use to authenticate a user.

> The [ADsOpenObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772238(v=vs.85).aspx) function binds to an ADSI object using explicit user name and password credentials.

This method is accepting the following parameters:

```
HRESULT ADsOpenObject(
  _In_  LPCWSTR lpszPathName,
  _In_  LPCWSTR lpszUserName,
  _In_  LPCWSTR lpszPassword,
  _In_  DWORD   dwReserved,
  _In_  REFIID  riid,
  _Out_ VOID    **ppObject
);
```

Using this method you can bind to object in Active Directory by specifying `username` and `password`.

If the bind is successful, the return code is `S_OK`, otherwise you'll get different error messages.

I don't write programs in `C++` on a daily basis. I typically work with `Active Directory` and `Active Directory Lightweight Services` in a `C#` world. But this sample code I wrote, shows you how to call `ADsOpenObject` method to bind to an ADSI object using specified credentials. In your case, just `authenticate`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "activeds.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   HRESULT hr;
   IADsContainer *pCont;
   IDispatch *pDisp = NULL;
   IADs *pUser;

   CoInitialize(NULL);

   hr = ADsOpenObject( L"LDAP://yourserver",
               L"username",
               L"password",
               ADS_FAST_BIND, //authentication option     
               IID_IADs,
               (void**) &pUser);


   if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
   {
      cout << "Successfully authenticated";
   }
   else
      cout << "Incorrect username or password";
   return hr;
}
```

Depending on your setup, you might have to tweak `ADS_AUTHENTICATION_ENUM`. I suggest you install **SSL Certificate** and use `ADS_USE_SSL` binding. Dealing with passwords without SSL in AD, can be nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  That did get me on the path I think, as I started playing with the different options in ldapsearch.  Please see my edits above.  Also, I don't think the AdsOpenObject library is available for Linux.  If so, I can't find it any way.  This looks like a nicer way to do it.

Comment: @kiss-o-matic, I believe your issue is how you bind. Since you are using default port, you're not using secure. Check this [link](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ldap_simple_bind_s) out. It explains different bind options.

Comment: If that was the case, how did it work with ldapsearch?  I'm pointing to the default port, and it works just fine.

Comment: I don't see you specifying any password in your ldap search.

Comment: The creds structure -- then passed in ldap_sasl_bind_s() - 4th argument (after mechanism).  Right?  Although I'm wondering what user it would try to authenticate that against.

Comment: Is your LDP search part of that c++ code you posted? Or it's a stand alone. Your LDAP search doesn't contain any passwords, so it's using your credentials to do any authentication in the background.

Comment: ldapsearch is a standalone, command-line program.  I was just using it to see what info my AD Server is expecting.